# Who was chosen the best soccer player of the 1958 world cup, Didi or Raymond Kopa?

Tags: football

In this video, tv sports journalist Maldini claims in the 1958 World Cup, Raymond Kopa was chosen the best player of the World Cup over Didi, Pelé, Garrincha and Vavá.

[Best 11 soccer players of France (spanish)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQjiXuhHlSk&t=10m23s)

And in this article, it's claimed that Didi received the golden ball award of the 1958 world cup, an award which is supposedly given to the best player of the world cup, and which its existence before 1978 is in debate.

> A teenage Pele was only denied the Golden Ball at in 1958 by team-mate
> Didi

[100 World cup heroes](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/worldcup2014/article-2573020/100-World-Cup-heroes-60-41-Sportsmails-countdown-continues-Bergkamp-Milla-Batistuta-Banks.html)

Who was chosen the best soccer player of the 1958 World Cup, Didi or Raymond Kopa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Didi was given it.

The Golden Ball award for best player was not officially given (in its current form) until 1982. Awards from before this time may be somewhat disputable, but nevertheless...

[FIFA's official website](https://static.fifa.com/fifa-tournaments/players-coaches/people=63855/index.html) lists Didi as the recipient of the 1958 (and 1962) World Cup Golden Ball awards. One may presume that the organization responsible for the event knows who was awarded what.

[The same source](https://static.fifa.com/fifa-tournaments/players-coaches/people=174677/index.html) lists Raymond Kopa as receiving the "France Football Ballon d'Or - FIFA World Player Gala" as well. This is *not* the World Cup Golden Ball award. Either Maldini is confused about the names, has used an alternative inaccurate source, or made up the claim themselves.